# In Azure Envrionment is Better to use Threading or Task library

Tags: azure, task

Im planning to use workerprocess in azure for long running task. But im coonfused whether to use Task parallel library or Threading.

-Mahender

Answer (score 0):

We've used TPL with some success in Azure and I would recommend it.  Without knowing more about your project, I'd say that you should be good to go ahead with TPL.

Answer (score 0):

Since a worker role (or web role) is scaffolding code running within a Windows Server virtual machine, I see the decision being based on your app and related architecture, not on Windows Azure. I'd choose the one you'd use if deploying to Windows Server. Just remember to properly catch any errors/exceptions in the `Run()` method since, if you exit `Run()`, the instance will go through its shutdown sequence and be recycled.

Answer (score 0):

TPL supports long running tasks with a special [TaskCreationOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx) enumeration member: LongRunning

> Specifies that a task will be a long-running, coarse-grained
>   operation. It provides a hint to the TaskScheduler that
>   oversubscription may be warranted.

And TPL makes it much easier to use multiple cores of your CPU. In Windows Azure you can have multiple CPU cores [based on the instance size you choose](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud/gg663909.aspx):

- Medium: 2 Cores
- Large: 4 Cores
- XLarge: 8 Cores

As opposed to simply using Threads, Tasks (TPL) allow you to use most out of the CPU cores available in your instance.

Answer (score 0):

How long is a long running task?

Workflow Foundation is a good option if the task needs to wait for external input or if it lasts a significant time, as you can serialize the task state to a database. The database can be created in Windows Azure SQL Database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735967(v=vs.90).aspx

The task scheduler can be enabled in Cloud Services (with some hacking around) which gives you another option.

The parallel task library is a good choice for short compute intensive workloads. Creating a thread requires some compute and memory overhead, so the TPL helps here by maintaining a thread pool upon which your tasks are executed. However if you need to block for a long time, or you want to run lots of thread simultaneously, it's perhaps not the best choice, and you should think about managing the threads yourself.

More details of your requirements would us make a better suggestion.